# passport-local does not pass message

Tags: passport.js, passport-local, flash-message

Error happens here (!user==true):

```
if (!user) {
        console.log('---2');
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username.'});
    }
```

Router config:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      console.log('Message:'+req.flash('message'));
      res.render('index', { title: 'Title', message: req.flash('message') });
    });

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/users/home',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
    }));
```

Console log shows, that message arrives empty. But message comes perfectly from another function (captcha check, using the same req.flash). Passport config:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
...
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'mySecretKey', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

var initPassport = require('./bin/auth/init-passport');
initPassport(passport);
```

Answer (score 0):

What a stupid mistake, never trust tutorials, always read docs... Passport passes messages via **error** property, not *message* property, so addition to Jade template are:

```
if error!=''
    div.form-group.alert.alert-danger
        p #{error}
```

Correction in routes:

```
res.render('index', { 
    title: 'Title', 
    message: req.flash('message'),
    error: req.flash('error') 
});
```

Be also careful with success message - it is returned also via special property, **success**.